MacBook Air 6.2 mid 2013 4GB ram i5 dual processor 512GB ssd takes too long startup
I am running MacBook Air 6.2 mid 2013 4GB ram i5 dual processor 512GB ssd with Catalina installed. It is eligible to run Big Sur but that was too slow.
So, I erased the ssd and did a clean install Catalina and it works well.
Except for the startup, it takes almost a minute before the Apple logo appears.
I can't find the bootlog and I don't know what to look for.
Could any one please advise?
